# ActionController::RoutingError when js => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec-rails, poltergeist

None of my tests have an error, except the one I'm adding with js => true.  Oddly enough the test would pass if not for a routing error.

My test:

```
context 'Javascript', :js => true do
  visit careers_path
  page.should have_content("Your Recommendations")
end
```

I can actual `puts page.body` and see that the content is there, but it still comes up with this routing error.  I notice that while running the actual server and it comes up with a `GET` request for the assets folder.  I don't understand why or what is doing this, but it seems to be the cause of failure.

The errors:

While running `rails s`

```
Started GET "/assets/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-12 19:11:02 -0400
Served asset / - 404 Not Found (5ms)
```

While running `rspec`

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
ActionController::RoutingError:
  No route matches [GET] "/assets"
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in `block in call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `each'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:19:in `call'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 # /Users/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

On a side note, adding `config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true` to config/environments/test.rb allows the test to pass, it does not explain why it is happening, it merely suppresses the warning

Comment: I used to see this sometimes - it usually came from some hard coded css background-color url or other url - look for those and you'll probably get rid of the warning.

Comment: why would it complain about a hardcoded url?

Comment: Say in your css file you have a :url(/assets/rest_of_your_path) or a :url(assets/rest_of_your_path), this will cause the error you see above if your hard coded path is wrong.